# ASP.NET Core 5 Enforcing HTTPS Except on Healthcheck

Tags: docker, asp.net-core-mvc, openid-connect, amazon-elb, .net-5

So I have been looking at an issue with our login process using OpenId-Connect through Okta. The site locally works as intended, and goes through the full pipeline of OAuth calls and returns a successful login. However, when I try to do this on a deployed version of the application, it is failing. Upon closer inspection it looks like the redirect URL for the Login page is using HTTP instead of HTTPS and the AWS ELB is listening ingress of HTTPS. I did some digging and read up on how to further enforce HTTPS by adding the following code to my Configure Services Section:

```
services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
{
    options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.STatus308PermanentRedirect;
    options.HttpsPort = 443;
});
```

After doing this, my deployment pipeline failed because my healthcheck started failing because the healthcheck is configured for HTTP Traffic, and is now returning a Redirect. I want to avoid having to change the ECS Task definition and docker file if at all possible. Is there something that I am missing in my ConfigureServices or Configure method? I have already used app.UseHsts() and app.UseHttpsRedirection in Configure.

Comment: Do you mean you used asp.net core healthcheck? Could you please share your startup.cs settings for healthcheck? Does your application enable both http and https?

Comment: @BrandoZhang I didn't use the built-in asp.net core health check. It is just a separate controller called Health check. I have never used the built-in asp.net core health check, would that possibly solve some of my problems?

Comment: In the application the ELB is only open to port 443, but on the docker container itself it is mapped to port 80 as to prevent having to use open ssl (this is coming from our DevOps team). The problem I am trying to get around at the end of the day is the OpenID-Connect is issuing a response using http even when I navigate using HTTPS, so I was hoping that enforcing HTTPS Redirects that it would solve the problem. I am not able to reproduce the problem locally which makes it even more frustrating.